# How to pass SOAP headers with JAXWSProxyHandler

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, apache-axis, opentext

I'm trying to use Opentext Content Web Services(CWS) from my axis2-based web-service.

This is a piece of code that creates a proxy client to CWS and passes an authentication token in a header.

```
DocumentManagement_Service docManService = new DocumentManagement_Service();
DocumentManagement docManClient = docManService.getBasicHttpBindingDocumentManagement();

    try
    {
        // The namespace of the OTAuthentication object
        final String ECM_API_NAMESPACE = "urn:api.ecm.opentext.com";

        // Create a SOAP header
        SOAPHeader header = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getHeader();

        // Add the OTAuthentication SOAP header element
        SOAPHeaderElement otAuthElement = header.addHeaderElement(new QName(ECM_API_NAMESPACE, "OTAuthentication"));

        // Add the AuthenticationToken SOAP element
        SOAPElement authTokenElement = otAuthElement.addChildElement(new QName(ECM_API_NAMESPACE, "AuthenticationToken"));
        authTokenElement.addTextNode(authToken);

        // Set the SOAP header on the docManClient
        String ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY = WSBindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY;

        ((WSBindingProvider) docManClient).setOutboundHeaders(Headers.create(otAuthElement));
    }
    catch (SOAPException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Failed to set authentication SOAP header!\n");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        return;
    }
```

This code works fine when executed from simple java application. In that case docManClient is a **SEIStub** object and **setOutboundHeaders** method works after casting to WSBindingProvider.

But when this code is executed inside my axis2 webservice, docManClient is **JAXWSProxyHandler** object and it can not be casted into WSBindingProvider nor execute setOutboundHeaders method.

So my question is - How do I pass my header with AuthElement using **JAXWSProxyHandler** (do the same as setOutBoundHeaders method do) OR Can I somehow convert JAXWSProxyHandler object to SEIStub object?

Comment: I am also stuck at exactly this point. Can you please post your answer that helped you to solve the issue ?

Comment: As I mentioned down below, I've casted JAXWSProxyHandler to javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider and found a way how to pass headers to it. As I remember I've just read documentation on javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider class and looked for examples of passing headers using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs because you are using an API that is specific to the JAX-WS implementation in the JRE. However, when running on Axis2, the JAX-WS implementation provided by Axis2 will be used instead. That implementation supports a different set of API extensions.

What this means is that your code is not portable across different JAX-WS implementations. You have two options:

- Make it portable by only using standard APIs. In your case this would require implementing a JAX-WS handler that adds the header. To pass the authToken to the handler, you would cast the client to `BindingProvider` and add the data to the request context.
- Remove the `axis2-jaxws` JAR from your Axis2 deployment so that your code will use the JAX-WS implementation from the JRE. Of course this won't work if the service itself is deployed as a JAX-WS service. Unfortunately the code snippet doesn't show whether that's the case or not.

Comment: Thanks for answering. However I have found a solution myself already. It seems that I used first option you mention. I did cast JAXWSProxyHandler to javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider and than modified SOAPHeader in a different way. Thank you.